# Jquery quiz percentage is not correct

Tags: jquery

I wrote a percentageCorrect function for a quiz I made but it is returning the wrong percentage when I call my function. Also, I have a seconds timer but I can't figure out how to have the minutes increase every 60 seconds. I tried using an if statement, for loop, etc. Here is my Jquery code below. Please help, thanks!

```
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var intervalId;
var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;
var timeSpent;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#results").addClass('hide');
    $('#questions').addClass('hide');
$('#startTrivia').on('click', function(){
    $('#questions').removeClass('hide');
    startTimer();
});

$("#submit").on('click', function(){
    $(".jumbotron").addClass('hide');
    $("#questions").addClass('hide');
    //get the number of correct... :checked is what the user checked
    var numberCorrect = $('input[data-correct="correct"]:checked').length;
    var numberIncorrect = 10 - numberCorrect;
    //puts in the html what questions were correct vs incorrect
    $('#correct').html(numberCorrect);
    $("#incorrect").html(numberIncorrect);
    timeSpent = "It took you " + minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds to complete the Thanksgiving Trivia!"
    $("#timeTaken").html(timeSpent);
    //calculating percentage of correct answers
    $("#totalPercent").html("You got " + percentCorrect(numberCorrect, numberIncorrect) + "% on the test!");
    //results will show after pushing submit
    $("#results").removeClass('hide');  
});

//timer pauses after clicking pause timer
$("#pauseGame").on('click', function(){
    pauseTimer();
    $("#questions").addClass('hide');
 });

//timer resets after clicking reset timer
$('#restart').on('click', function(){
    resetGame();        
    $("#questions").addClass('hide');
    $("#results").addClass('hide');
    $(".jumbotron").removeClass('hide');
    //clearing the checked radio buttons
    $("input:checked").removeAttr("checked");
    });
 });

// NOT GIVING CORRECT PERCENTAGE?
function percentCorrect(x, y) {
    return Math.round((x/y)*100);
};

// CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO MAKE MINUTES INCREASE EVERY 60 SECONDS?
function totalTime() {
    seconds++;
    $('#seconds').html(seconds);    
};

function pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
};

function startTimer() {
    intervalId = setInterval(totalTime, 1000);
};

function resetGame() {
    seconds = -1;
    totalTime();
    this.clearInterval(intervalId);
};
```

Comment: It would help to split this into two questions and indicate exactly what the issues with the calculations are.  What are the inputs?  What is the expected output?  What output are you getting?  Which function is returning the wrong value?

Comment: I think you are passing in the wrong values to your `percentCorrect` functions. `y` should be the total number of questions I think. Say you have 9 questions correct and 1 incorrect which would be (9/1)*100 = 900, whereas when `y` is the total number of questions (10) it would be (9/10)*100 = 90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calculating your percentage incorrectly. It should be:

```
percentageCorrect = (totalCorrect / totalQuestions) * 100
```

Also, in order to count the number of minutes:

```
if(seconds % 60  == 0) minutes++;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was so stumped. However, seconds needs to reset to 0 every 60 seconds. The percentage is now correct! I spent tons of time trying to figure it out because the functions math was correct. I added a variable totalQuestions = 10, the amount I have, and it was fixed. How do I reset seconds? I tried a few things but haven't figured it out yet.